# Duplicating of action due to refreshing the browser

Tags: php, html

I have created a set of codes where i use `isset($_GET['add'])` for adding items to cart.

But once I refresh the browser its duplicating. I think its kind of normal because the browser refresh the same url.

My only solution is to use `header(location:"")` to change the url.
But I want to create something that if you add to cart, the browser should not be refreshed.

Like for example HTML:

```
<a  href="cart.php?addsr='.$row['id'].'">ADD TO CART</a> `

if(isset($_GET['add'])) { 
    /* FUNCTIONS HERE */
    header('location:'.$page);
}
```

All is good. Actually its working but, Is it possible to add to cart without refreshing the page?
My another option it to erase cart.php
Example :

```
<a  href="?addsr='.$row['id'].'">ADD TO CART</a>
```

But basically, when I refresh the browser it duplicates the items because of duplication of the action due to its same url.

Comment: How about setting a flag in local storage to see it items are present in cart. and taking action on page load depending upon the flag's value is true(items are present in cart) or false(items are absent in cart).

Answer (score 0):

In place of using anchor tag, you can use button and submit the data to specific url via jquery ajax so that page will not be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't avoid the refresh, you can add a random number or timestamp to the url:

```
<a  href="cart.php?addsr='.$row['id'].'&t='.time().'">ADD TO CART</a>
```

Then, in your php can set the "t" parameter in session and check if the last value are different.

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['lastItemCheck'] || $_SESSION['lastItemCheck'] != $_GET['t']) {
  /* Add the item to the cart */

  /* Set the $_SESSION variable as new t parameter */
  $_SESSION['lastItemCheck'] = $_GET['t'];
} else {
  /* This item was added to the cart, do nothing */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have another page called add-cart-item.php then have your process working in there. Then call that page via ajax on your main cart page.

Comment: yeah but when ever I refresh the page it comesback from its default content. How can I avoid this from happenning?

Comment: You may store the cart items inside a session variable or with javascript localstorage

Comment: what I mean is, after a function of jquery ajax load() it all comes back after refreshing the page.